# How to specify a property placeholder that references a YAML list in Spring configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I use [property placeholders](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.property-placeholders) to "inject" values into other properties in my YAML config files. Like this:

```yaml
a:
  b: Hello
  c: 123
  d:
  - One
  - Two
  - Three
x:
  y: ${a.b} There
```

This works well, the value of `x.y` is resolved as `Hello There`.

Now I want to reference the entire list `a.d`, but this does not work:

```yaml
x:
  z: The list is ${a.d}
```

Spring complains, saying:

> Could not resolve placeholder 'a.d' ...

I suspect I can reference individual elements in the a.d list, like `a.d[0]` but I want the entire list. Is that possible?

Comment: Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

This works when you use the syntax with '>'

Try doing this:

```
a:
  d: >
    One,
    Two,
    Three

x:
  z: The list is ${a.d}
```

Comment: In that example, isn't `a.d` just a string value (instead of a sequence/list), the same as if it were on one line like `d: One, Two, Three`?

Comment: No, you can read the properties as a List in your spring Java code